# How to use an outside variable in a PHP class?

Tags: php, class, variables

I have config.php with this...

```
$dbhost = "localhost";
```

I want to be able to use the $dbhost variable inside a class.

User.class.php

```
include 'config.php';    
class User {
    private $dbhost = ???
    }
```

There's a couple other questions like this, but they were for some other specific uses, and I guess it's just a basic thing that I can't really find anything else about it on the web.

**UPDATE: Wow, thanks for all the help everybody.  New to this site, but I might just stick around and give back where I can.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

several ways I think. 
First pass it to the class constructor:

```
include 'config.php';    
class User {         
    private $dbhost;

    function __construct($dbhost){
      $this->dbhost=$dbhost;
    }
}
$user= new User($dbhost);
```

Or use a setter:

```
include 'config.php';    
class User {         
    private $dbhost;

    function setDbhost($dbhost){
      $this->dbhost=$dbhost;
    }
}
$user= new User();
$user->setDbhost($dbhost);
```

Or using CONSTANTS:

```
define('DBHOST', 'localhost');
class User {         
    private $dbhost;

    function __construct(){
      $this->dbhost=DBHOST;
    }
}
```

OR using global:

```
include 'config.php';    
class User {         
    private $dbhost;

    public function __construct() {
    global $dbhost;
    $this->dbhost=$dbhost;
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all the ways and examples.  I ended up using constants as I didn't want to have to pass variables with every instance and didn't want to call a setter function for every instance.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a [global variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php), defining a [constant](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php) would be better, but using a setter/getter method is best. When you are using a class, any outside resource that it uses should be passed to it. This design patter is called [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) if you want to research it further.

In this example, I've combined the setter and getter into a single method, and included the ability to set the value when you first create the instance, using a constructor:

```
class User
{
    private $host = null;

    public function host($newHost = null)
    {
        if($newHost === null)
        {
            return $this->host;
        }
        else
        {
            $this->host = $newHost;
        }
    }

    function __construct($newHost = null)
    {
        if($newHost !== null)
        {
            $this->host($newHost);
        }
    }
}

//Create an instance of User with no default host.
$user = new User();

//This will echo a blank line because the host was never set and is null.
echo '$user->host: "'.$user->host()."\"<br>\n";

//Set the host to "localhost".
$user->host('localhost');

//This will echo the current value of "localhost".
echo '$user->host: "'.$user->host()."\"<br>\n";

//Create a second instance of User with a default host of "dbserver.com".
$user2 = new User('dbserver.com');

//This will echo the current value of "dbserver.com".
echo '$user2->host: "'.$user2->host()."\"<br>\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

For something like a db host, use a constant:

```
// define it first
define('DBHOST', 'localhost');

// then anywhere you can use DBHOST:
class User {
    function __construct() {
        echo DBHOST;
    }
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php

Comment: Although correct, my recommendation is don't do this. Inject the values you need into the class.

Comment: That worked great, thanks.  Didn't realize that would work inside the class.

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to use variables (and not constants), then use the following code.

In config.php

```
$dbhost = "localhost";
```

In User.class.php

```
include 'config.php';    
class User {
    global $dbhost;
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using global variables, they can create bugs that are hard/impossible to track down.

Comment: Even I don't favor the use of global variables and hardly use them. But I tried to answer what the user asked specifically.

Comment: The OP doesn't mention global variables.